# Service 'serviceName' failed to build: COPY failed: stat usr/src/backoffice/dist/backoffice: file does not exist

Tags: docker, infrastructure

i'm getting this new error while running 'Docker-compose build' on my server. it was working perfectly just yesterday. i did't change the Dockerfile.

ps: this error is occuring with every service i run and has the 'COPY' function in it

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9fgA.png)
Dockerfile:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDs1Z.png)

Comment: Please don't post text as images. It makes it really hard for users to copy-paste to their own machines if they want to try to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`ng build` puts the built app in `dist/`, so your COPY statement should be

```
COPY --from=build /usr/src/backoffice/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the probleme is that it is running in my local machine. but not in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Probleme solved !, i had to do a `docker-compose rm' and rebuild from scratch to get rid of the error.